# How do I calculate the inverse of a pyspark dataframe using pandas udf?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Apologies but I'm new to PySpark and this does not seem like a trivial operation to pull off.

If I have a PySpark Dataframe like so:

```
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
    |index| _1  | _2  | ... |_10000| 
    +-----++-----+-----+-----+-----+
    | 1   | 0.1 | 0.5 | ... | 0.9  |
    | 2   | 0.2 | 0.2 | ... | 0.1  |
    | 3   | 0.4 | 0.4 | ... | 0.3  |
    | 4   | 0.7 | 0.2 | ... | 0.2  |
    | ..  | ... | ... | ... | ...  |
    |10000| 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.4  |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+------+ 10000x10000
```

This Pyspark dataframe has 10000x10000 rows and columns. I want to calculate the inverse of the dataframe. I tried looking for resources but couldn't find any implementation for this. I was wondering how it can be done using pandas_udf. I am also open to any other approaches as well.

I am running the code in databricks with 64 cores and Pyspark 3.0.0

For instance the dataframe can be generated using this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, row_number, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import numpy as np
n = 10000
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([[np.random.rand() for i in range(0, n)] for j in range(0,n)]), 
)
df.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id()))).show()
```

Comment: Having added id as well in the dataframe. How do I approcah this? @mck

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "the inverse of the dataframe"?